# One-way binding on both sides of equation

Tags: html, angularjs

I was wondering how to use a one way binding on both sides of an equation in the html side of angularjs.

Example:

```
ng-if="::user.email !== ::vm.loggedInUser.email"
```

I get this parse error

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 17 of the expression [user.email !== ::vm.loggedInUser.email] starting at [::vm.loggedInUser.email)].

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to remove :: and use: ng-if="user.email !== vm.logged"

Comment: you are thinking about it wrong....you don't bind both sides...you one way bind the whole expression...remove second `::`

Comment: Oooh. All right thank you. I thought you had to apply it to each variable.

Comment: By the way if you feel like putting that in an answer I'll accept it since you answered first.

Answer (score 2):

So there is two possible fixes to this problem:
Either you can change the way of seeing the problem and begin seeing two separate exepressions instead of one. The code would be:

```
ng-if="::(user.email !== vm.loggedInUser.email)"
```

or you keep your mental model and use ng-show instead like:

```
ng-show="::user.email !== ::vm.loggedInUser.email"
```

Made a plunker to play with, showing the interaction: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/MPvWVsm4Kkyq9Yq4V0vi?p=preview

Comment: Why wouldn't the same expression work for both `ng-if` and `ng-show`? Why would they be evaluated differently?